# How did GTO: Shonan 14 Days end?

Tags: great-teacher-onizuka

I recently learned that Fujisawa had written an interquel to GTO called "Shonan 14 Days" where, as can be ascertained from the title, Onizuka Eikichi stays for 14 days in his hometown.

Could somebody give a rough description of how the series ended?

Comment: This site doesn't allow direct discussion of fansubs or scanlations to avoid legal issues. Hence, I had to remove a bit of your question. Your question is fine other than that, but if you want to edit more into the question please keep this policy in mind.

Comment: I am certainly not asking to be pointed to a scanlation of the "missing chapters" :) (precisely because of the points you raise); that is why I decided to be modest, and just ask for a summary.

Comment: About half the manga series has been translated into English. Because it has been released in order, the conclusion isn't available in English yet. I'm really looking forward to reading it when it is. It's really good.

Answer (score 1):

The manga takes place during a summer holiday Onizuka had while he teach Kanzaki Urumi's class. It started with Onizuka going back to his hometown, Shonan, for the holiday. Shonan is his base back during the day where he was known as the Onibaku (along with his best friend, Danma Ryuuji).

There, Onizuka met with a girl who works in an Orphanage like place, but instead of for kids with no parents, it was for kids with problematic parents. There, Onizuka helped the kids with their problems.

It ended with Onizuka chasing after the Mayor of the town after the Mayor's act caused one of the kids (a girl) with serious burn injury. With the help of his Onibaku underlings, he successfully caught the Mayor in a bus full of cabaret girls after posing as a terrorist bus hijacker. He then forced the Mayor to resign his office, apologize to the injured kid, and take care of her medical bills, including a plastic surgery to fix her damaged face.

At the end it was shown that Onizuka has returned to the school, with his students doubting his story (about his holiday) and then surprised to find that Onizuka didn't make up the story after one of the caretaker girls called him.